# Preview mode opens blank page

Tags: experience-editor

I am facing an issue that whenever I preview any page from the Sitecore content tree, it displays a blank page. Although the pages have the page design set correctly and are displayed correctly on the published site (CD).

I'm using `Sitecore 9.1.1 in a scaled environment`.

Any idea what might be causing this issue?

***Update:*** sc_site query string parameter is not resolving the correct current site name. The issue is that its always getting sc_site=website

Comment: Any errors in the Sitecore logs and/or in your browser console?

Comment: are you getting the same in experience editor as well?

Comment: Is the site context being set properly? Try to check the querystring sc_site and an existing sitename

Comment: Are you using SXA and have you looked into the SXA Site manager? Also, check your site groupings (Valid for environment field), maybe you only have a site grouping for your CD and not for you CM environment.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue. Initially i used to clear out the "sc_website=" value. But deep diving into the issue, it was basically due to the incorrect sites config. One of the site with an incorrect hostname was getting resolved.

Make sure to check the sites config thoroughly and patch it before website.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multi-site. Check your site definition defined, in this case, Sitecore appends `Sc_site = website` in URL, which causes this issue as per my experience.

The workaround is when you see `sc_website= website`, remove it manually and check the response.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore is not able to identify your website. Check that you site definition is correct and contains a unique hostname to identify your site correctly -

```
    <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <sites>
      <site name="<your site name>" patch:before="site[@name='website']"
            virtualFolder="/"
            physicalFolder="/"
            rootPath="/sitecore/content"
            startItem="/home"
            hostName="<you site hostname>"
            database="web"
            domain="extranet"
            allowDebug="true"
            cacheHtml="true"
            htmlCacheSize="50MB"
            enablePreview="true"
            enableWebEdit="true"
            enableDebugger="true"
            disableClientData="false"/>
    </sites>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```